# How to dynamically load a class in different location and get the method names in the class in python

Tags: python, inspect

I have wriiten the Simple class .py file which has the class 
class Employee:

```
empCount = 0

def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
    Employee.empCount += 1

def displayCount(self,salary):
    print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

def displayEmployee(self):
    print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary
```

and now i have written the another script to import the file and get the methods in the class but i am not able to fetch the methods

```
import inspect
import sys
pat="E://pythonscripts"
sys.path.append(pat)

#pat="E:/pythonscripts/Simpleclass"
__import__('Simpleclass', globals={})

for name, method in inspect.getmembers('Simpleclass', inspect.ismethod):
    print name
    (args, varargs, varkw, defaults) = inspect.getargspec(method)
    for arg in args:
        print arg
```

when running the inspect script i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/stack.py", line 9, in <module>
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(Employee, inspect.ismethod):
NameError: name 'Employee' is not defined
```

Comment: so you want to import it?

Comment: I cant see `for name, method in inspect.getmembers(Employee, inspect.ismethod):` in above code

Comment: I have given the classname Simpleclass in the for loop

Comment: Where is `Simpleclass` initialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add path of the `employee.py` module in `sys.path`

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<directory of employee.py module>)
```

For import dynamic module use `__import__`

```
__import__('employee', globals={})
```

**OR**

[importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html)

You can use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) for introspecting python class

```
import inspect

for name, method in inspect.getmembers(<your class>, inspect.ismethod):
    print name
    (args, varargs, varkw, defaults) = inspect.getargspec(method)
    for arg in args:
        print arg
```

Comment: But this doesnot work if it  is in different path means emplyee class in one path and inspect file is in another path

Comment: I have wriiteen the following codeimport sys
pat="E:/pythonscripts"
sys.path.append(pat)

#pat="E:/pythonscripts/Simpleclass"
__import__(Simpleclass, globals={})                        but it is throwing the error  as        name 'Simpleclass' is not defined  So please can you tell  wat is the mistake

Comment: Will you please update your question with latest code?

Comment: You can use `employee = __import__('employee')` to import it as a module. Use `employee.Employee` to access that class.